# Css distribute text over 2 lines and vertically align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a layout like the image in the link below. It's basically a set of list items that contain some text and then a large number to the right. I am wondering if it would be possible to distribute the text where it's outputted over 2 lines even though there is no fixed width on the list item elements

Additionally, i am looking for a cross browser solution to vertically align the text and the numbers inside the LI. It needs to work in IE7+ without any javascript

[image]

Comment: IE7, no JS, cross browser, vertical align... hate to say it but you need `display: table`!

Comment: Thank you Andy, does display:table work in IE7 ? I checked http://caniuse.com/css-table and it says IE7 doesnt support it. Thanks

Comment: No, IE7 doesn't support `display: table`.  Are you able to split the text from the numbers (eg. `<span>To Verify</span> <span>3220</span>`)?

Comment: This might be your best bet for maximum browser support (excludes IE7), but it isn't great:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/fp9vlis7.  It would be easier if there was a `:first-word` selector, but there isn't :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="top">To</div>
    <div>For Submit<span class="number">50</span></div>
    </li>
<li>
    <div class="top">To</div>
    <div>For Submit<span class="number">50</span></div>
    </li>
<li>
    <div class="top">To</div>
    <div>For Submit<span class="number">50</span></div>
    </li>    
<ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
list-style:none;
font-size:14px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

ul li {
background-color:gray;
display:inline-block;
padding:5px 10px;
}

.number {
margin-left:10px;
font-size:20px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kkWuU/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but the text is dynamic so it's not possible to wrap the first line in 1 div and the 2nd line in another.

Comment: but how you gonna be decided that which text should come to first line and which one is in second line?

Comment: Could i specify a cross browser min-width value to make things go onto the second line if necessary ?

Comment: I think it would be `max-width` not `min-width`. `max-width` will take care that container would never go beyond this value

Answer (score 0):

### First solution: navigation bar

I think that you need basically a navbar.

Twitter Bootstrap navbar is the best thing you can chose I say.
See the [**documentation**](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar).

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

See live example: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6SRnP/).

### Second solution

Also, you can use `row`s and `span`s.

Documentation is [**here**](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1">Text 1</div>
    <div class="span1">Text 2</div>
    <div class="span1">Text 3</div>
    <div class="span1">Text 4</div>
    <div class="span1">Text 5</div>
    <div class="span1">Text 6</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v92H7/)

Comment: The OP already has the navbar appearance they're looking for, TB cannot solve the rest of the OP's problem.